# Signing app gets error: Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I've been developing an app in Ionic for some months which is expected to be live by the end of November and I wanted to start some tests with some users. In the process, I bought the App Developer program already, set up an app Id as requested and shipped the code to Xcode with capacitor.

When I'm trying to configure the whole thing to be built, more precisely when I configure the signing options, I choose the profile I created and I get the following error, which prevents me from building:

```
Failed to create provisioning profile.
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website.
Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
```

I've been searching about this and I read somewhere I would need an iPhone to make it work properly. It happens I don't own an iOS device and I don't mean to.

I would like to know what would I need to do to make it work without having to buy an iPhone.

Comment: Its not required to have an iphone, but at least you should have a mac, so in your apple account , you could set the mac as your device, and mac will be an apple product. Second you need to create a profile in apple certificates and identifiers, and set the profile to use your distribution certificate.

Comment: @MostafaHarb how can I set up the device? I'm new to this. About the certificate, I guess I already did it, but can you explain me as well? Also, please post an answer with all the info so I can choose it as the solving one.